# How to use the Async Component way to import component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a question about Async Component.

I got a error message when try to import a component using Async Way.

Is it possible to do that or My concept totally wrong about using Async Component way ?

> Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

My Dashboard Component

```
<template>
<div>
    <logout></logout>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    const logout = resolve => require(['./child/Logout'], resolve)
    export default {
        name: 'dashboard',
        components: {
            logout
        }
    }
</script>
```

Logout Component

```
<template>
    <div class="view logout">
        <el-button>Logout</el-button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'logout'
    }
</script>
```

Comment: does your `logout` component have a template to display?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot put my logout component here, but nothing special thing in logout component.

Comment: @tommychoo I tried your code and it worked. Could you please check your vuejs's version? https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KqhJzfxEB98MA9pAsAo